# Find values for which matrix becomes singular in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Let's take the following square matrix:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[10.0, -498.0],
             [-2.0, 100.0]])
```

A will be singular if its determinant (A[0,0]*A[1,1]-A[0,1]*A[1,0]) is zero. For example, A will be singular if A[0,1] takes the value -500.0 (all else unchanged):

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

y = symbols('y')
eq = Eq(A[0,0]*A[1,1]-y*A[1,0])
sol = solve(eq)
sol
```

How to find all values (A[0,0],A[0,1],...) for which A (or any given square matrix) becomes singular efficiently (I work with large matrices)? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there's no way to find each possibility of singularity of a matrix other than bruteforcing, maybe recursion functions can come in handy here other than for loops... (i guess)

Comment: do SVD decomp and set one of the singular values to 0

Comment: I dunno why my previous comment was upvoted, i don't think it's what OP wanted but might be worth looking into, so i won't delete it yet. Here's what i think you need: omit the column of the value which you want to change. if the resulting matrix is singular, find the linear combination of rows that gives you the row at which to want to change the value you omitted. find the new value using the linear combination you found.

Comment: Hey do you accept a brute force type of finding singular of a square matrices?

Comment: @yannziselman thanks for the suggestion, I will try this out.

Comment: @GhostOps I am fine with brute force but I work with big matrices (1e7x1e7) and it needs to be reasonably operational (hours not days). Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: Dont know but the code that i have now will work only for square matrices, is it okay for you? as it runs recursively, it throws a recursion error, thats it, other than that, it works very well. Do you want it?

Comment: @GhostOps I work with square matrices (will edit question) so I would love to have a look at it, thanks.

Comment: Hey @David, i've posted my code as an answer, take a look at it, is that what you are looking for dude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use Laplace expansion to calculate the determinant. The formula is

```
det(A) = sum (-1)^(i+j) * a_ij * M_ij
```

So to make a matrix singular, you just need to use the above formula, change the subject to a_ij and set det(A) = 0. It can be done like this:

```py
import numpy as np

def cofactor(A, i, j):
    A = np.delete(A, (i), axis=0)
    A = np.delete(A, (j), axis=1)
    return (-1)**(i+j) * np.linalg.det(A)


def make_singular(A, I, J):
    n = A.shape[0]
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if i != J:
            s += A[I, i] * cofactor(A, I, i)

    M = cofactor(A, I, J)
    if M == 0:
        return 'No solution'
    else:
        return -s / M
```

Testing:

```
>>> M = np.array([[10.0, -498.0],
                  [-2.0, 100.0]])
>>> make_singular(M, 0, 1)
-500.0000000000002

>>> M = np.array([[10.0, -498.0],
                  [0, 100.0]])
>>> make_singular(M, 0, 1)
'No solution'
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach seems to work as intended. I was wondering if there's any chance to make it a bit faster? When using it with the matrix I am working with (7872x7872) it takes 13 hours to compute the solution for each coordinate.

Comment: To increase the speed, you can calculate the 7872x7872 cofactors first and save the values in a matrix. Then, reuse the cofactor matrix in `make_singular()`.

Comment: Btw, the cofactor matrix can simply calculated using the math formula: `C = det(A) * inv(A).T`, so you don't need to loop through every row, column index.

Comment: From 13 hours to 20 seconds, that's what I call a speed boost! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This thing works for square matrices...

What it does is it bruteforces through every item in the matrix and check if its singular, (so theres a lot of messy output, ue it if you like it tho)

And also very important, it is a Recursive function that returns a matrix if it is singular. So it throws RecursiveError recursively....:|

This is the code i have come up with, you can use it if its okay for you

```
import numpy as np

def is_singular(_temp_int:str, matrix_size:int):
  kwargs = [int(i) for i in _temp_int]

  arr = [] # Creates the matrix from the given size
  temp_count = 0
  for i in range(matrix_size):
    arr.append([])
    m = arr[i]
    for j in range(matrix_size):
      m.append(int(_temp_int[temp_count]))
      temp_count += 1

  n_array = np.array(arr)
  if int(np.linalg.det(n_array)) == 0:
    print(n_array) # print(n_array) for a pretty output or print(arr) for single line output of the determinant matrix
  _temp_int = str(_temp_int[:-len(str(int(_temp_int)+1))] + str(int(_temp_int)+1))
  is_singular(_temp_int, matrix_size)

# Only square matrices, so only one-digit integer as input
print("List of singular matrices in the size of '3x3': ")
is_singular('112278011', 3)
# Just give a temporary integer string which will be converted to matrix like [[1, 1, 2], [2, 7, 8], [0, 1, 1]]
# From the provided integer string, it adds up 1 after every iteration
```

I think this is the code you want, let me know if its not working